# How would I evaluate $\int{x!}dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How would I evaluate $\int{x!}dx$? Obviously elementary functions will not suffice. I looked up this problem on Google and have found no results. I've tried to logically think about this and haven't reached any conclusions. Obviously, the antiderivative of $x!$ implies that there must be a function whose derivative is $x!$. I've looked at the graph of $x!$ and it seems like you can cut the factorial at $x = 0$. The positive side resembles an exponential graph, while the negative side is more complicated. Is there any way to approach this?

(Also, this isn't for an assignment or anything, I was just interested in whether there is a way to take the antiderivative of a factorial. I'm also only in AP Calculus BC so I'm not an expert in this.)

Comment: The factorial is only defined on integers, so you can't integrate it as a real function.  There is an extension of the factorial to the reals called the gamma function,  which you may want to look into. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: If you use $$
x! = \int_0^{ + \infty } {t^x e^{ - t} dt} ,
$$ you get $$
\int {x!dx}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^x  - 1}}{{\log t}}e^{ - t} dt}  + C.
$$ It seems that $$
\int_0^z {x!dx}  \sim \frac{{z!}}{{\log z}}
$$ as $z\to +\infty$.

Comment: The asymptotics can be proved using L'Hôpital's rule and the asymptotics of the digamma function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider $x!$ as a step function, this integrals boils down to

\begin{gather}
\sum_{i=1}^n i!
\end{gather}

which can be rewritten in terms of recurrence relations as
$f(n) = f(n-1) + n!$ for which the solution is $f(n) = (-1)^{n + 1} Γ(n + 2)\ \ !(-n - 2)\, +\, !(-2)$ where $!x$ is the subfactorial function and $Γ$ is the gamma function (the extension of the factorial to the reals)